# I am a little bit confused about Sliding Cache Expiration. Hope someone can clarify it for me

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have been reading sliding cache expiration and thinking about implementing one for my application. But I am a little bit

According to MSDN : .SlidingExpiration indicates whether a cache entry should be evicted if it has not been accessed in a given span of time.

So this is the method call

```
Cache.Insert("SlidingExpiration", cacheData, null,
System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

The above code uses sliding expiration. it means if cache is not accessed within 1 minute. But what if the cache is accessed within this 1 minute, will it still be expired in sliding expiration?

Please advise. That is what I am confused about.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, at any point in time, the object has not been accessed for 60 seconds, then it will be deleted.  If it has been accessed with the past 60 seconds then it cannot be deleted at that point in time.  Any access of the item ensures that it will be kept alive for another 60 seconds.

Comment: so, let's say if you keep on accessing the item in cache within the 1 minute frame, it will be kept in the cache forever, until your application recycles?